# How to limit a query in Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I am trying to query a data extension which stores email  to get back subscriber key, the DE  stores email from a cloud page form so that I could redirect them to a profile center by making a custom URL based on the subscriber key, the issue is the query returns subscriber key for all email in data extension and I am trying to limit it to the 1 entered. I know the limit doesnt work with a join but is there any way to limit it to just one record or is there any better way of getting subscriber key for the email entered.

```
SELECT s.email ,c.SubscriberKey
FROM InputDE s
LEFT JOIN _Subscribers c 
ON c.EmailAddress = s.email
```

Answer (score 3):

If you mean "de-duplicate by email address" when you say "limit it to just one record", then you can do something like this:

```sql
SELECT top 1 with ties
  s.email 
, c.SubscriberKey
FROM InputDE s
INNER JOIN ent._Subscribers c ON c.EmailAddress = s.email
order by row_number() over (paritition by s.email order by s._customObjectKey desc)
```

This query picks the most recent (`top 1 with ties`) email (`paritition by s.email`) in `InputDE` where the recency is based on the hidden id field `_customObjectKey` -- a higher value is newer (`order by s._customObjectKey desc`).

Comment: I am getting this error with your query "The 'Ent.' prefix can only be used to query data in a parent account from a child account."

Comment: Just remove the `ent.`, since you're running this at the parent.  Leaving it off on queries in the child BUs is something I see often.

Answer (score 0):

This slight change to Adam's solution works for me.

```
 SELECT top 1  s.email,c.SubscriberKey
FROM InputDE s
INNER JOIN _Subscribers c ON c.EmailAddress = s.email
order by row_number() over (partition by s.email order by s._customObjectKey desc)
```

Comment: leaving off the `with ties` is not going to deduplicate it by email.